# I want to show $X$ is independent of $X$ if and only if $X$ is a degenerate random variable .

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variables on probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal B, P)$.Then, show that $X$ is independent of $X$ if and only if $X$ is a degenerate random variable .
(i.e,tehre is a $c \in \mathbb R$ such that $X=c$ almost everywhere)

Comment: If $X$ is not degenerate, then there exists $c$ so that $0 < P(X<c) < 1$.  Is that enough to let you finish?

Comment: @GEdgar.thank you but I need more.

Comment: If $u = P(X<c)$, show that $u^2=u$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\mathbb P\{X\geqslant c\}\in\{0,1\}$ for each $c$. Define 
$$c_0:=\inf\{c\mid \mathbb P\{X\geqslant c\}=0\}$$
and show that $X=c_0$ almost everywhere.